# How to process data after reading from QIODevice.read()?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qiodevice

This is my first time to ask question, if there are something I get wrong, please tell me, I will be appreciate.

I am using QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler for a custom url, and I want to use QFile to open a javascript file for testing.

First, if I just use

```
QFile("ken.js")
```

The window could open the javascript, but if I use my custom QFile,
I have no idea how to process the data after I read from QIODevice.read().

I want to know what I need to do to make the window could open the javascript after I read the data from QIODevice.read().

Please give me some suggests, thank.

Here is my full code.

```
class TestQFile(QtCore.QFile):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFileName(fileName)
        self.open(self.ReadOnly)

        self.data = b''

        while True:
            receivedData = self.read(10)
            self.data += receivedData
            if receivedData == b'':
                break

class TestHandler(QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    def requestStarted(self, request):
        self._dev = TestQFile("ken.js")
        request.reply(b'text/javascript', self._dev)


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._view = QWebEngineView(self)
        self._handler = TestHandler() # Must keep ref
        self._view.page().profile().installUrlSchemeHandler(b'myuri', self._handler)
        self._view.setHtml('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="d1"></div><script src="myuri://test/ken.js"></script></body></html>')
        self.setCentralWidget(self._view)
        self.show()
        self.raise_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = TestWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if the class inherits from QFile you do not have to do anything since it already has implemented the methods that QWebEngineUrlRequestJob requires since it will use the methods that every class that inherits from QIODevice must implement as readData(), writeData(), atEnd(), etc.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore,QtWebEngineWidgets

class TestQFile(QtCore.QFile):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFileName(fileName)

class TestHandler(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    def requestStarted(self, request):
        self.file = TestQFile("ken.js")
        request.reply(b'text/javascript', self.file)

class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self._handler = TestHandler() # Must keep ref
        self._view.page().profile().installUrlSchemeHandler(b'myuri', self._handler)
        self._view.setHtml('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="d1"></div><script src="myuri://test/ken.js"></script></body></html>')
        self.setCentralWidget(self._view)
        self.show()
        self.raise_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for suggest.
I know it can just setFileName(), and works fine.
If I want to use an <audio>, and transfer the data on network,
is it possible to use QIODevice for receiving?

Comment: @s105321521 What is your goal to inherit from QFile?

Comment: My goal is to transfer audio data from my server to client, the client is a browser which has a tag <audio> for receiving data and play it.

Comment: @s105321521 So you should not inherit from QFile but from QIODevice I have to implement all the virtual methods according to your requirements, that is independent of QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler.

Comment: @s105321521 On the other hand, if my answer helps you solve the problem that you point out in your question, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]

Comment: Yes, I use QIODevice first, but I don't know how to handle it, so I try to use QFile for understanding how QFile process data, if I read data, where I can put the data to the browser. But I still don't understand. I'm so grateful for your helping.

Comment: @s105321521 I think that what you want is already partially done, you should use QTcpSocket which is a QIODevice and can access the data of your server through socket.

Comment: OK, I will try it. It's helpful. Thanks.